# How to add custom "pay now" button and after submit, redirect to the checkout/orderId page

Tags: commerce

In the *Deal details page* I want to add a new button *Pay Now* and then user clicks it, then redirects to the *checkout/orderId* page. How is it possible ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rule. Example:

```
{ "rules_forward_user_directly_to_checkout" : {
    "LABEL" : "Forward user directly to checkout",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_order", "rules", "commerce_cart" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_add" : [] },
    "IF" : [],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "checkout" } } ]
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need to redirect to `checkout/%order_id`, you just need to redirect to `checkout` and Commerce will take care of the rest.